# Numpy: Imputing NaN values either buggy (sklearn) or doesn change the array

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Currently I'm trying to get rid of NaN values in a large numpy array. If I apply the Imputer from sklearn, it assumes that some of the columns in the array consist only of NaNs and discards them - though only the first few rows match this assumption.

I figure that this behaviour has to be a a bug and therefore, I can not use this tool (unsurprisingly, I need the dumped columns). But performing an hands on approach using a median, I end up with a totally unchanged array. :(

This is my code, x_train being a numpy array:

```
x_train = x_train.T
for column in x_train:
    median = column[int(len(column)/2)]
    column[column == np.nan] = median
    column[column == np.inf] = 0
    column[column == -np.inf] = 0
x_train = x_train.T
```

Printing the first row of the array before and after the operation I end up with two identical rows:

```
[  4.40572853e-01   4.39998817e-01   4.44360730e-01   4.01524000e+02
   4.01524000e+02   4.01524000e+02   4.83419270e-02   4.82160365e-02
   4.91767511e-02              nan              nan              nan
              nan              nan              nan   3.33333333e+01
   3.33333333e+01   3.33333333e+01              nan              nan
              nan]
```

What am I missing here? I did a lot of googling and if the answer is already out there, I must have been searching in a completely wrong direction. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `np.isnan` and `np.isinf` rather?

Comment: Does not change a thing. Thanks for the input, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column is not sorted and contains nans sou you should use `np.nanmean()`
And you should use `np.isnan()` instead of `==`.

```
x_train = np.array([[np.inf, 1, 1, np.nan], [2, 2, np.nan, 2,], [10, np.nan, 10, 10]])

print(x_train)

x_train = x_train.T
for column in x_train:
    # median = column[int(len(column)/2)] 
    median = np.nanmedian(column)
    # column[column == np.nan] = median
    column[np.isnan(column)] = median
    column[column == np.inf] = 0
    column[column == -np.inf] = 0
x_train = x_train.T

print(x_train)
```

Prints

```
[[ inf   1.   1.  nan]
 [  2.   2.  nan   2.]
 [ 10.  nan  10.  10.]]

[[  0.    1.    1.    6. ]
 [  2.    2.    5.5   2. ]
 [ 10.    1.5  10.   10. ]]
```

Comment: Of course columns are not sorted, how could I not see this?

Your code works for my application, thank you very much. :)